# Array formation incorrect while adding new array in existing array

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to add an array to exiting array. Its getting added but array inside array is what the out.

Current scenario

```
         Array
        (
        [t373980] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 373980
                [name] => Ability
                [depth] => 0
                [startMonday] => 0
                [hidden_name] => selected_agency[373980]
                [parent_tid] => 0
                [full_label] => Ability
                [full_tid] => 373980
                [expanded] => 0
            )

        [t414605] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 414605
                [name] => Ad Council
                [depth] => 0
                [startMonday] => 0
                [hidden_name] => selected_agency[414605]
                [parent_tid] => 0
                [full_label] => Ad Council
                [full_tid] => 414605
                [expanded] => 0
            )

        [t0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [t] => Array
                    (
                        [tid] => 0
                        [name] => (Blank)
                        [depth] => 0
                        [startMonday] => 0
                        [hidden_name] => selected_agency[0]
                        [parent_tid] => 0
                        [full_label] => (Blank)
                        [full_tid] => 0
                        [expanded] => 0
                    )

            )
         )
```

** what I want is **

```
      Array
        (
        [t373980] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 373980
                [name] => Ability
                [depth] => 0
                [startMonday] => 0
                [hidden_name] => selected_agency[373980]
                [parent_tid] => 0
                [full_label] => Ability
                [full_tid] => 373980
                [expanded] => 0
            )

        [t414605] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 414605
                [name] => Ad Council
                [depth] => 0
                [startMonday] => 0
                [hidden_name] => selected_agency[414605]
                [parent_tid] => 0
                [full_label] => Ad Council
                [full_tid] => 414605
                [expanded] => 0
            )

       [t] =>  stdClass Object
                    (
                        [tid] => 0
                        [name] => (Blank)
                        [depth] => 0
                        [startMonday] => 0
                        [hidden_name] => selected_agency[0]
                        [parent_tid] => 0
                        [full_label] => (Blank)
                        [full_tid] => 0
                        [expanded] => 0
                    )
         )

         $no_agency_arr =array("tid"=>"0", "name"=>"(Blank)", "depth"=>0, "startMonday"=>0, "hidden_name"=>"selected_agency[0]", 
                  "parent_tid"=>"0", "full_label"=>"(Blank)", "full_tid"=>"0", "expanded"=>0); 
        $no_agency_obj = (object)$no_agency_arr; 
        $final_no_agency_arr["t"] = $no_agency_obj; 
        array_push($out,$final_no_agency_arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$no_agency_arr =array("tid"=>"0", "name"=>"(Blank)", "depth"=>0, "startMonday"=>0, "hidden_name"=>"selected_agency[0]", 
                  "parent_tid"=>"0", "full_label"=>"(Blank)", "full_tid"=>"0", "expanded"=>0); 
//you need array so no need to convert it to object. so comment/remove it out.
        //$no_agency_obj = (object)$no_agency_arr; 
        $final_no_agency_arr["t"] = $no_agency_arr; 
//why are you using it when you already assigned value in that array. so comment it, 
//if `$out` if the final array which you are printing, so you need to assign value in it instead of `$final_no_agency_arr` like:
 $out["t"] = $no_agency_arr; //don't forget to comment out the above line
        //array_push($out,$final_no_agency_arr);
```

[Check here for reference](https://3v4l.org/WigK6)

Comment: it got added at the bottom of array. I need at first position.

Comment: you can use `array_unshift() — Prepend one or more elements to the beginning of an array`  but key would be different - https://3v4l.org/ZTjC8

Comment: or you can use `ksort($final_no_agency_arr)` after `$final_no_agency_arr["t"] = $no_agency_arr;`

Answer (score -1):

In your code replace this

```
$no_agency_obj = (object)$no_agency_arr; 
$final_no_agency_arr["t"] = $no_agency_obj;
```

with this

```
$final_no_agency_arr["t"] = $no_agency_arr;
```

No need to create an object if you just need an Array!!

Comment: I need that to convert to object

Comment: What is the purpose behind it? Can you please explain?